# How to find user, which last modified a view

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a view called 'employee' in a database called 'db'

With the following query I can see that the last time the view was altered is on '2022-10-07 12:55:14.238 +0000':

```
select * from db.information_schema.tables where TABLE_NAME = 'employee'
```

However I have no information on the user which altered it.

Is there a query that would allow me to find the name of the user which altered the view?

Answer (score 0):

The SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.QUERY_HISTORY view records the history of queries executed in an account. We can trace the user who has done a particular activity, in this case, the user who last modified a view, by using a filter accordingly

```
use role ACCOUNTADMIN;

SELECT START_TIME,USER_NAME,QUERY_TEXT
FROM SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.QUERY_HISTORY
WHERE START_TIME >= '2022-09-01' 
AND START_TIME < '2022-09-31'
AND QUERY_TEXT ILIKE '%ALTER VIEW%<VIEWNAME>%'
ORDER BY START_TIME DESC;
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/access_history.html#access-history-view

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/access-history.html#access-history

The OBJECTS_MODIFIED column available in the snowflake.account_usage.access_history view can be used

```
SELECT USER_NAME
       , QUERY_ID
       , QUERY_START_TIME
       , DIRECT_OBJECTS_ACCESSED
       , BASE_OBJECTS_ACCESSED,OBJECTS_MODIFIED
FROM ACCESS_HISTORY
ORDER BY 1, 3 DESC
;
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/query_history.html#query-history-view

Answer (score 0):

Column `LAST_DDL_BY` contains information about user:

```
SELECT LAST_DDL_BY, LAST_DDL, *
FROM SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.VIEWS;

SELECT LAST_DDL_BY, LAST_DDL, *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS;
```

[VIEWS View (Information Schema)](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/VIEWS-View-Information-Schema-New-Columns-in-View):

> `LAST_DDL_BY`  Username of the user who performed the last DDL operation on the table or view.